# Using Handler for a long time method

Tags: android

I am using Handler to make the UI responsive when doing search. I used Handler but why it still displays the error "Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views".

```
@Override
public void onClick(final View view) {
    if (view.getId() == R.id.searchButton) {
        processThread(searchEditText.getText().toString());
    }
}

private void processThread(final String word) {
    progressDialog.show();

    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            // This is a long time method.
            searchWord(word);

            searchHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        };
    }.start();
}

private void searchWord(final String word) {
    final String result = dictionaryClient.lookup(word);
    resultTextView.setText(result);
}

private final Handler searchHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    };
};


07-04 22:04:54.699: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8815): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException:
Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
07-04 22:04:54.699: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8815):     at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2802)
07-04 22:04:54.699: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8815):     at android.view.ViewRoot.requestLayout(ViewRoot.java:594)
07-04 22:04:54.699: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8815):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8125)
07-04 22:04:54.699: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8815):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8125)
07-04 22:04:54.699: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8815):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8125)
07-04 22:04:54.699: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8815):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8125)
07-04 22:04:54.699: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8815):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8125)
07-04 22:04:54.699: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8815):     at android.widget.ScrollView.requestLayout(ScrollView.java:1200)
07-04 22:04:54.699: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8815):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8125)
07-04 22:04:54.699: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8815):     at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:5371)
07-04 22:04:54.699: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8815):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2688)
07-04 22:04:54.699: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8815):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2556)
07-04 22:04:54.699: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8815):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:2531)
07-04 22:04:54.699: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8815):     at com.megadict.activity.DictionaryActivity.searchWord(DictionaryActivity.java:135)
07-04 22:04:54.699: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8815):     at com.megadict.activity.DictionaryActivity.access$1(DictionaryActivity.java:133)
07-04 22:04:54.699: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(8815):     at com.megadict.activity.DictionaryActivity$2.run(DictionaryActivity.java:146)
```

Edit: I followed [this article](http://thedevelopersinfo.wordpress.com/2009/10/19/using-handler-for-long-time-operations-in-android/) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this line in `searchWord`:

```
resultTextView.setText(result);
```

That needs to be executed on the UI thread but is running in the search thread. Replace it with:

```
searchHandler.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        resultTextView.setText(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: This answer is not best but it works with my question! I decided to use AsyncTask instead.

Answer (score 1):

the problem with your searchWord method it still updates the UI from another thread,try to keep the code in Handler

```
private final Handler searchHandler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(final Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
//call searchWord method from here depends upon your logic
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I answered a similar question to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569545/alert-dialog-not-showing/6569953#6569953).

It's much easier to write AsyncTask classes to replace all your threading/messaging code, and simplify typical "show dialog/do background task/stop dialog" applications.

The code I wrote there could be a direct drop in for your code, replacing the `doLogin()` with your `searchWord()`.

I would strongly suggest every instance you think of writing a Thread and Handler to replace them with an AsyncTask class.